# Access object created by another thread without invoking every time?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, controls, invoke

I have a simple status label that I update frequently during a long running routine.  The routine is on a timer and thus on another thread, so I get the `Cross-thread operation not valid` error.  I found a fix on SO, which looks like this:

```
lblQuery1Status.Invoke(new Action(delegate
{
    lblQuery1Status.Text = "Status: Publishing";
}));
```

However, I update the text of this control 7 or 8 times during the routine.  Is there a more efficient or simple way to do this?

Comment: What's inefficient about it? If you need to do it 7-8 times, stick it in a method called with status as string input. I'm looking at your rep and I'm truly not trying to be snarky - just curious as to what you're communicating when you say efficient?

Comment: I guess I was wondering if I could invoke it once in the new thread instead of every time I need to access it.  I'm new to `.net` and especially threading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to "simplify" the syntax, you can always use an inline lambda to "shorten" the syntax:

```
lblQuery1Status.Invoke(new Action(() => lblQuery1Status.Text = "Status: Publishing"));
```

You can also create an action variable for the invoke and re-invoke the action whenever needed:

```
Action updateStatus = () => 
    lblQuery1Status.Invoke(new Action(() => lblQuery1Status.Text = "Status: Publishing"));
```

You can then invoke it as a method as many times as needed:

```
updateStatus();
```

Comment: Yes, I knew `invoke` wasn't creating new threads, I was just hoping there was a way to invoke it once *on* the new thread and reference it multiple times afterwards (without invoking each time)

Comment: @Scott ah, my mistake.  Does the last update get any closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: Definitely, the Action handle looks interesting. I'll research it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I went with, based on [@David L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1165998)'s [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398172/access-object-created-by-another-thread-without-invoking-every-time/39398351#39398351).

Action definition:

```
Action<string> updateStatus = (s) => 
     statusLabel[qo.id].Invoke(new Action(() => statusLabel[qo.id].Text = s));
```

Call:

```
updateStatus("Opening Connection");
```

I realize it's no more efficient but it's much simpler and cleaner and it makes me cringe less.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatley it's the best way to get data from your long running task/thread to the UI thread, marshalling has its overheads but unless you're calling it hundreds of times a second I think you'll be fine